# Trying to add discord cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a discord cog from replit that isnt mine. I have no experience at all with cogs, so this is confusing for me. I got the bot to work, but the actual sudo command does not as it does not understand the message that you input in it to sudo. How would I fix the bot?

```
from copy import copy

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

__version__ = "1.0.0"

class SudoCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(
        hidden = True
    )
    #@commands.is_owner()
    async def sudo(self, ctx, victim: discord.Member, *, command):
        """Take control."""
        new_message = copy(ctx.message)
        new_message.author = victim
        new_message.content = ctx.prefix + command
        await self.bot.process_commands(new_message)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(SudoCog(bot))
```

Edit: here is the second python file

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
import setuptools


def getLongDescription():
    with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
        longDescription = fh.read()
    return longDescription


def getRequirements():
    requirements = []
    with open("requirements.txt") as f:
        requirements = f.read().splitlines()
    return requirements


def getVersion():
    path = Path(__file__).parent.resolve() / "sudo.py"
    with open(path, "r") as fp:
        version_file = fp.read()
    version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]", version_file, re.M)
    if not version_match:
        raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")
    version = version_match.group(1)
    return version


setuptools.setup(
    name="DigiSudo",
    version=getVersion(),
    author="DigiDuncan",
    author_email="digiduncan@gmail.com",
    description="Sudo command cog for discord.py.",
    long_description=getLongDescription(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/DigiDuncan/DigiSudo",
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    install_requires=getRequirements(),
    py_modules=["sudo"],
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)"
    ]
)
```

Comment: There should be some code that is loading the cog automatically if it is in a cogs folder or there is a command that dynamically loads said cog. You'll have to show code of your existing bot with existing cogs that are loaded.

Comment: can you show us the python code that runs the bot?

Comment: you need to load the cog in main.py using `client.load_extension('foldername.filename')`